# Why am I getting this NoSuchMethodError?

Tags: dart, error-handling, compiler-errors, command-line-interface

I have this code

```
String encrypt(String x) {
    String out;
    var _x = x.codeUnits;
    List dict;
    /* <dict_assignment> */
    dict[0] = 'a';
    dict[1] = 'b';
    dict[2] = 'c';
    dict[3] = 'd';
    dict[4] = 'e';
    dict[5] = 'f';
    dict[6] = 'g';
    dict[7] = 'h';
    dict[8] = 'i';
    dict[9] = 'j';
    /* </dict_assignment> */
    _x.toList().forEach((i) {
      var _i = i.toString();
      _i.split("").forEach((k) {
        var _k = int.parse(k);
        print(_k);
        print(dict[_k]);
        out += dict[_k];
      });
    });
    return out;
  }
```

(Yes I'm writing HTML tags as comments in Dart...sue me)
(Idk why my indentations are messed up)

For some reason when I use this same function with a random string like this

```
var x = encrypt("hmm interesting");
```

I keep getting this

```
Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]=' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []=(0, "a")
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
```

Please help me I'm actually confused why this is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not initialized your `dict` variable, so it contains `null`.

If you change `List dict;` to `List dict = [];` then *that* would start working.
You also haven't initialized `out`.

The remainder of the code is leaning towards being overly complicated, and can be optimized as well. Here is a suggestion:

```dart
String encrypt(String x) {
  var out = StringBuffer();
  const dict = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];
  for (var i in x.codeUnits) { // x.codeUnits is a list. Use for-in to iterate it.
    for (var k in i.toString().codeUnits) {
      var _k = k ^ 0x30; // Best way to convert code unit for 0-9 into integer 0-9.
      // print(_k);
      // print(dict[_k]);
      out.write(dict[_k]); // Use a StringBuffer instead of repeated concatenation.
    }
  }
  return out.toString();
}
```

It does not appear to be a decryptable encryption. The string `"77"` and the string `"ᖳ"` (aka `"\u15b3"`) both encrypt to "ffff".

Or, if you want to "code-golf" rather than be readable or close to the original, it can also be a one-liner:

```dart
String encrypt(String x) => [
      for (var i in x.codeUnits)
        for (var k in "$i".codeUnits) "abcdefghij"[k ^ 0x30]
    ].join("");
```

Comment: jeez i need to learn more about bit operations but thanks for the answer tho